# how can I get how many numbers of api are getting called in my component?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I my project we use redux, so we have methods to call api's. Is there any way that I can know when I navigate to a particular component some "x" number of api are called.

if I am navigated to /home I should get response like 
api : ["/userNames", "/versions" , "/userData"]

Is there any way to get response as above or get similar kind of response.
I want to use this information to show/hide loader spinner.It should show " loading... "if on that particular page any one of the api is still in pending state. It should hide loading only if all the apis are either successfully called or failed.

Comment: Any code that might help us?

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to add flags to your redux state. For example, you can have `fetchingUsersNames` set to `true` when you make the request and `fetchedUserNames` set to `true` when the request finishes. Repeat for each of the API calls. (Note: feel free to find better names.)

Then in your component, you can use these flags to guide your rendering logic.

Comment: or make it a number an each time before making a request increment it and after the request decrement it so you can have acces to the number of pending requests

Comment: @AhmedSbai That's a great idea and probably better than my solution.